# Completeness relation of kraus operators not satisfied in Fake backends

Tags: qiskit, noise, kraus-representation

With the following code

```
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import FakeGuadalupe
from qiskit.providers.aer.noise import NoiseModel
import numpy as np

backend = FakeGuadalupe()
nm = NoiseModel.from_backend(backend)

print(nm._local_quantum_errors['cx'][(0,1)].circuits[0])
print(len(nm._local_quantum_errors['cx'][(0,1)].circuits[0][1][0].params))

k11=np.transpose(nm._local_quantum_errors['cx'][(0,1)].circuits[0][1][0].params[0].conj())*nm._local_quantum_errors['cx'][(0,1)].circuits[0][1][0].params[0]
k22=np.transpose(nm._local_quantum_errors['cx'][(0,1)].circuits[0][1][0].params[1].conj())*nm._local_quantum_errors['cx'][(0,1)].circuits[0][1][0].params[1]
k33=np.transpose(nm._local_quantum_errors['cx'][(0,1)].circuits[0][1][0].params[2].conj())*nm._local_quantum_errors['cx'][(0,1)].circuits[0][1][0].params[2]
print(k11+k22+k33)
```

I get the following output:

```
     ┌────────────┐┌───────┐
q_0: ┤0           ├┤ kraus ├
     │  Pauli(II) │├───────┤
q_1: ┤1           ├┤ kraus ├
     └────────────┘└───────┘
3
[[1.        +0.j 0.        +0.j]
 [0.        +0.j 0.99257842+0.j]]
```

But I think that this means that the completeness relation of the kraus operators is not satisfied. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I don't know how the noise model is derived in this context, but have you considered the possibility that real noise does not preserve trace (i.e. you have loss)?